# Joomla - Unset multiple session variables not working

Tags: session, joomla

I thought this would be simple but I guess there's a catch somewhere...
I'm developing a custom part of code for a Joomla installation and I need to unset some session variables before executing my code. So, naturally, I have

```
$session->clear('var1'); 
$session->clear('var2'); 
$session->clear('var3'); 
$session->clear('var4');
```

but the page appears totally blank and nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you got the $session variable like this:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
```

If you are getting a blank page, you probably some error in your code. Do you have access to some kind of error log? If not, you can try to force displaying errors from your code if it's not a production environment (although it's not the best way to do it) or enable debug mode from the joomla administrator.

You can also try to run the php file in your browser, and if everything is ok and there are no parse errors in the file, you should see a message like 'Restricted access' or similar.

Besides, if the script is not crashing, you can check what value is returning each call to $session->clear( 'xxx' ) (It should return the value you just cleared.

The last thing that comes to my mind is that the vars you have stored in session are in a different "context". When you get/set data to session, you can pass a "namespace" as an additional parameter, so these vars are stored in that "namespace" (in fact, it's stored inside another index inside the session. So if possible, you should check if these variables are stored in session using a different "namespace":

```
$session->set( 'var1', $value, 'another_namespace' );
```

If so, you should clear it like this:

```
$session->clear( 'var1', 'another_namespace' );
```

P.S.: I said "namespace" because it's the parameter name that Joomla uses in these session methods, but don't get confused with PHP namespaces.

I hope it helped!