# How to Clear Session in Joomla

Tags: session, cookies, joomla

how to clear sessions in joomla?
How to solve this issue.
When I clear session in browsers like firefox, chrome it is not deleting the sessions in jnp_sessions table. And I am checking who have already logged in. Here the code for multiple logins.

```
$db = JFactory::getDB();
$query = "select user_id from jnp_sessions"
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
$userid = $db->loadObjectList();
return $userid;
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567737/joomla-unset-multiple-session-variables-not-working

Answer (score -1):

To destroy session:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->getSession()->destroy();
```

To get list already login user:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBo();
$query = "select userid from #__sessions where guest=0"
$db->setQuery($query);
$userid = $db->loadObjectList();
return $userid;
```